# Passing multiple JSON filenames to pandas and adding to a dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas

I'm working on the following code, where I am passing filenames from a variable "filelist", then performing some pandas dataframe procedures including obtaining data and filtering columns.

```
filelist=filestring
li=[]
merged_df=[]

for file in filelist:
    # temp df
    df=pd.read_json(file)
    # filter columns
    df2=pd.DataFrame(df[['a','e']])
    #find data from each JSON
    epf=df['s']['d']['Pf']
    ep=pd.json_normalize(epf, record_path=['u','D'], meta=['l','dn'])
    #append data from each JSON and add to li_dframe
    li.append(ep)
    frame=pd.concat(li,axis=0,ignore_index=True)
    #merge filtered columns and li_dframe
    merged_df=pd.concat([df2,frame.reset_index(drop=True)],axis=1).ffill()
    print(merged_df)
merged_df.head(n=40)
```

Where I am having trouble is in the final merged data frame, I can only see data from one of the underlying Json files - the second in the list. This is strange as the print function, shows that the code has correctly handled both JSON and extracted the required values. Can anyone advise what I am missing here to correctly ensure the merged_df has all the necessary info?

Comment: Your loop overwrites `merged_df`, so it prints the correct dataframe each time, but then overwrites it each time as well.

Comment: How would I correct that?